# C# Non-constant int inside Constant?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, constants

I'm learning the basic functionality of constants in C# and our teacher gave this piece of code just as an example.

I just tried it out but the compiler gives the error "The expression being assigned to must be constant". And it makes sense that the values inside constants must also be constant so I just defined "int date" as a constant and BAM!, works just fine.

***But my question is:***

Why did our teacher give this example? Maybe he's used to other programming languages and forgot about this detail?

```
    int date = 2017;
    const int birthday = date - 1980; // Gives compiler error
    int age = date - birthday;
```

**vs**

```
    const int date = 2017;
    const int birthday = date - 1980; // Doesn't give error
    int age = date - birthday;
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: How do we know why your teacher gave that example? Probably just a mistake.

Comment: Maybe he comes from a C and/or C++ background? `const` in C# requires the values to be compile time constants. The first example would work with `readonly` instead of `const`

Comment: @UnholySheep: You're right in concept, wrong in the details.  C# wouldn't accept that code because it doesn't allow `readonly` on a local variable.

Comment: @MartinSmith he litterally said "let's say we're working with variables, for instance if _birthday = 1980_ we could still do _const int age = birthday + 20;_ but if we tried to change the age variable in any other way, we would get a compiler error"So that's why I got confused.

Comment: Teachers, even good teachers, do get things wrong sometimes.